# How to iterate through variables by reference c#

Tags: c#, list, oop, reference

In one class I have a bunch of class variables that hold the position of game pieces. After a move I need to iterate through those variables and change each of them. 
The problem I ran into was that by simply making a list and adding these variables, their values get passed into the list and changing the list elements does not change the variables.

```
int _var1;
int _var2;
int _var3;

List<int> varList = new List<int>() { _var1, _var2, _var3 };
for (int i = 0; i < varList.Count; i++) 
{
    varList[i]++;
}
```

Something like this does not work.

I feel like I'm missing some really simple oop concepts here but I can't think of how to iterate through all these variables without doing something more complicated than feels necessary for just one method.

Comment: Why do you want to iterate and set the values of the variables? Variables in your class will always be fixed.

Comment: You say these variables are inside a class right? In that case make a `List<YourClass>` and interate through that instead.

Comment: First of all, it won't allow to use unassigned variables in List. Why you want do this unnecessary stuff?

Comment: @Loocid I tried to execute this code and VS shows me some red lines with error "Use of unassigned variable _var1"

Comment: @GaurangDave Sorry, you're right... Don't know what I was thinking of then.

Answer (score 0):

[Value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) are copied when you add them to List. List allocates different memory.

Even though it's better not to have side effects, function should return [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples) of values and you set them explicitly.

If you want to pass them by reference you need to wrap it in object:

```
    public class ValueStorage
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var _var1 = new ValueStorage() { Value = 0 };
            var _var2 = new ValueStorage() { Value = 1 };
            var _var3 = new ValueStorage() { Value = 2 };

            var varList = new List<ValueStorage> { _var1, _var2, _var3 };
            for (int i = 0; i < varList.Count; i++)
            {
                varList[i].Value++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @SimplyGed you are right, fixed this part. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: No problem. I'll delete my comment as it no longer makes sense :-)

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Maybe I'm missing something but I have no clue how to do the same without pointers unsafe code and type casts. If you know better way post it as an answer and I will upvote it.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen boxing wont help, unboxing creates another copy

Comment: If you want to go that way there is the Int32.
Int32 _var1 = 0;
            Int32 _var2= 10;
            Int32 _var3 = 20;

            List<Int32> varList = new List<Int32>() { _var1, _var2, _var3 };
            for (int i = 0; i < varList.Count; i++) 
            {
                varList[i]++;
            }

            foreach (Int32 item in varList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

Answer (score 0):

you can make a class and put your Var1,Var2 and Var3 in it and initialize and object and call them in a loop.

something like this.

```
List<MyClass> obj_list = get_the_list();

foreach( MyClass obj in obj_list ){ obj.property = 42;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just how value types work. Boxing wont help either

From the specs  **1.3 Types and Variables**

> When a value of a value type is converted to type object, an object
>   instance, also called a “box,” is allocated to hold the value, and the
>   value is copied into that box. Conversely, when an object reference is
>   cast to a value type, a check is made that the referenced object is a
>   box of the correct value type, and, if the check succeeds, the value
>   in the box is copied out.

- You will need to store them in a reference type
- or another trivial way is to use an array of pointers (`int*`). (This is assuming an array is suitable), this would allow functional transformations without the need to encase them in another type

**Example**

```
private int _var1 = 1;
private int _var2 = 2;
private int _var3 = 3;

...

var varList = new[] { &_var1, &_var2, &_var3 };

...

foreach (var value in varList)
   *value += 1;

Console.WriteLine(_var1);
Console.WriteLine(_var2);
Console.WriteLine(_var3);
```

**Output**

```
2
3
4
```

---

**Additional Resources**

- [Value Types (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types)
- [Pointer types (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/pointer-types)
- [unsafe (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe)